# 2D Density or Frquency Scatter Plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I make a scatter plot colored by density in matplotlib? 
When I plot a colorbar it shows density scale, I want counts/percentage instead. How to convert density estimation to frequency counts?

Expected result is Fig.3 on page 8 of this paper: https://www.atmos-meas-tech.net/9/3293/2016/amt-9-3293-2016.pdf

If anyone can guide me to draw a plot similar to one shown in paper, it will be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cax=ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=10, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```

Another Method Tried:

```
#libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kde

# create data
x = np.random.normal(size=500)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=500)


# Evaluate a gaussian kde on a regular grid of nbins x nbins over
nbins=50
k = kde.gaussian_kde([x,y])
xi, yi = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):nbins*1j, min(y):max(y):nbins*1j]
zi = k(np.vstack([xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()]))

# Add color bar
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.reshape(xi.shape), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Counts are bound to a bin size... so unless you create a histogram of some sort your question doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: @Julien Can you kindly suggest some solution to this?

Comment: Well as I said: define a bin size and create a histogram...

Comment: @Julien : I tried creating bins and created histogram bu scale bar units are in density. I want them in Frequency count or percentage format.

Comment: where's that code?

Comment: @Julien : You can see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a histogram, it's just sampling your kde on a grid...

Try this: `plt.hist2d(x, y)`

you can specify the bins using `bins=whatever` argument and many more options...

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I tried plotting using hist2d. It creates a 2D histogram. Actually I want to create a plot exactly similar to one in the paper. I want scatter points and colored by density but I want color scale in the form of frequency count or percentage.

Comment: Well that still doesn't make any sense: the "count" or "percentage" of any single point of a probability distribution is 0, only density make sense at single point. If you want a finite "count" or "percentage" value you need to consider intervals not single points... I think you need to clarify to yourself what you want to do.